# JNIUS & TIKA - error trying to parseToString

Tags: java, python, apache-tika, pyjnius, tika-server

tried to run the tike-app with jnius but got a problem (macOS Sierra, Java 1.8 JDK, Python 2.7 & Python 3.6)
Everything works fine (output for tika.detect is fine)  until the `parseToString` command. It seems there's a pop up showing off if you run this command
(tested with a java program too and it works). But running with jnius it stops working and there's no output and no error.

```
import os

os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "tika-app-1.14.jar"
from jnius import autoclass
from jnius import JavaException

# Import the Java classes
Tika = autoclass('org.apache.tika.Tika')
Metadata = autoclass('org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata')
File = autoclass('java.io.File')

# Raise an exception and continue if parsing fails
try:
    file = File('./source/test.doc')
    tika = Tika()
    meta = Metadata()
    detectText = tika.detect(file)
    print(detectText) # Working the output is: application/msword
    contentText = tika.parseToString(file) #here it stops no further steps are executed
    print(contentText)
except (JavaException,UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
    print("ERROR: %s" % (e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i've found the solution. There's a option for the JVM missing 
telling the tiki.jar to use the headless Mode.

```
#Config have to be before import minus
import jnius_config
jnius_config.add_options('-Djava.awt.headless=true')

import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "tika-app-1.14.jar"

from jnius import autoclass

## Import the Java classes we are going to need
Tika = autoclass('org.apache.tika.Tika')
Metadata = autoclass('org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata')
FileInputStream = autoclass('java.io.FileInputStream')

tika = Tika()
meta = Metadata()
text = tika.parseToString(FileInputStream("./source/test.doc"), meta)
print(text)
```